# Changing Spring configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a class that reads some properties from this application.properties and add them as configuration properties to the java/spring application. What I am trying to achieve now is this: I do deliver the package to the client, and inside this application.properties there are database connection details, so the client can change them. The question is, can this be done in the stage after we create the .war file. So basically the client goes and changes the configuration file, and on deploy these configs will be used, or that must be done prior building the .war file. Attached you will see my solution:

//application.properties

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://ip\\instance:port;databaseName=db_name
db.username=db_username
db.password=db_pass
```

//WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use environment variables? Those can be easily changed by clients without having to resort to deployment tricks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is with [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial). It's a directory (lookup) service specifically designed for providing database connections, properties, and other runtime configuration data to packaged Java EE applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your connection information in your server (tomcat, jboss or other). There are specific files to do that (in tomcat it is the context.xml file for example).

After, you can use this information in your application using datasource. So, when the war file is deployed on the server, the connection information are known.

Comment: The thing is that I have other variables in that file as well. And I need to change them time to time.

Comment: You can split your properties file or (if possible), put the other db variables in the same file in your server. But, the best way will be to insert static data (for the connection) in the server and the others in a file with your application. What do you have in your properties file ?

Comment: I have for example:
api_url,
facebook_id,
twitter_id.

And if the instance is running when i change this file the changes are not reflected to the app

Comment: So, why you don't try to split information in two properties or xml files ? Your own DB information will have to be in a specific file. The others information in a file like that : externalConnection.properties

Comment: Ok lets say i have splitted them in two files. Why when the client changes the externalConnection.properties the changes are not done to the application? Do I need to redeploy?

Comment: If there are changes in your properties files, you have to redeploy in your case indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of packaging up `application.properties`, why not have it as an externally referenced file, e.g.:

```
@PropertySource("file:/external/path/to/application.properties")
```

This would allow clients to change the file without modifying your packaged distribution.

Answer (score 0):

### Common classpath way

In a most servlet containers there is common folder where you can store classpath resources available for all web applications. You can use this folder for configuration purposes. Change your build process to do not include `application.properties` into the final war file. You can prepare for example another maven project for such config files aside. Provide a copy of `application.properties` in your deployment documentation. During deployment you need to adjust properties in provided `application.properties` file according to your environment and then place it in a folder that is common for all webapplications. For Tomcat it is `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` folder. During development you can add a folder with this property file to server classpath via launch configuration. As a downside you can have naming conflicts between two webapps that use the same approach (two `application.properties` files).